# What is the correct term for a tool that filters content based on metadata?

Tags: custom-post-types, search

I am creating a resource library for students at my online school that will be searchable with metadata. Many sites such as [WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/search?qt=worldcat_org_all&q=ronald%20dahl) have a tool on the left-hand side where you can filter or refine content (look at the div tag "FormatRefinement" in the example) based on metadata.

What is this functionality called? Intuitively, it would seem to be called a 'content filter' but any search for filters brings me to the WordPress Codex where it discusses 'hooks and filters.' I've tried searching for the correct terminology myself but, after several months, no luck. Thank you.

Comment: juste search for "search" and you will find this kind of plugins : https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-search/ https://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/

Comment: This is for text searches but not for filtering based on metadata as shown in the WorldCat example in the question.

Comment: Maybe Taxonomy is the term you are looking for? A taxonomy is essentially a term or way of categorizing meta data associated with a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After additional research, the answer appears to be that the term **"taxonomy"** encompasses the two sorting tools most common in WordPress. Those are **categories**, which can be hierarchical, and **tags**, which cannot have a parent-child relationship.

A simple example would be a custom post type called *cafes* in which you might have parent categories such as districts, child categories such as neighborhoods, and various tags to describe the general atmosphere.